# When will I get an arraystoreexception and a classcastexception with respect to generics?

Tags: java

My understanding is that you get an [ArrayStoreException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html) when you try to insert an object of incompatible type.

```
Object[] array = new String[1];
array[0] = 1;
```

Can someone explain, with an example, when will I get an [ArrayStoreException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html) and when will I get a [ClassCastException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) ?

Answer (score 2):

A `ClassCastException` is casting to a wrong subclass, refer to Java 1.6 API for all exception and class information.

This is an example taken from the API:

```
 Object x = new Integer(0);
 System.out.println((String)x);
```

Answer (score 0):

A ClassCastException would happen if you did something like this:

```
public void stupidMethod(Object o)
{
    //Classcast if o is not a String
    String s = (String)o;

    //do more stupid things
}
```

An arraystoreexception is similar:

```
public void stupidMethod()
{
    Object[] array = new String[2];
    //whoops arraystoreexception
    array[0] = new Integer();
}
```

You should read the API for these exceptions in the future instead of posting here.

Just google `java api (class name)` and you shall be rewarded with more information than I am willing to type out.